# Display a message to website by implementing Python, RabbitMQ, NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js, rabbitmq

I have a project that uses Python for the backend, RabbitMQ as middleware, and NodeJS for the frontend. Is there any method to display a simple "Hello World!" to the website using Python, RabbitMQ, and NodeJS? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Flask for a simple hello world like so:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="localhost", port=5000)
```

running this file should open the server for connections, you can then connect to `http://localhost:5000` in a browser of your choice to see if your web server is up and running.

Comment: But the project requires to use of RabbitMQ, so from what I understand, python will send the message to RabbitMQ and then RabbitMQ. After doing something, RabbitMQ will send the message to the NodeJS to display on the browser, in this case, is port 5000

Comment: I'm not familiar with RabbitMQ, however, you can try plugging in the [hello world tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html) to your back-end and see if it functions as you would expect it to. You would also need to facilitate RabbitMQ sending those messages to your front-end, which is then not a python question anymore...